# Calcular usando as operações Matemáticas no LESS

Tags: less

Estou tentando somar um **number** com uma **string** e o LESS não está interpretando como eu queria, veja o exemplo:

```
@screen-sm: 768;
@screen-md: 1024;

.col-tablet(@rules) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm+'px') and (max-width: @screen-md+-1+'px') {
        @rules();
    }
}

.col-tablet({
  display: block;
});
```

e a saída:

```
@media (min-width: 768 'px') and (max-width: 1024+-1 'px') {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que em Less não precisa somar **number** com **string**

Faça o seguinte, altere suas variáveis para:

```
@screen-sm: 768px;
@screen-md: 1024px;
```

Creio que esteja fazendo uma subtração quando executa:

```
@screen-md+-1
```

Sendo assim altere para:

```
.col-tablet(@rules) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm) and (max-width: (@screen-md - 1)) {
        @rules();
    }
}
```

Para mais **informações** e **exemplos** de como usar, acesse o compiler do less http://winless.org/online-less-compiler